# Get all paths neo4J Cypher

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I'm using neo4j to develop a proof of concept and I want to get all Nodes ID for all paths from my root node to leafs, example with ids :

```
ROOT1-->N1--->SN2--->L1
ROOT1-->N2--->SN3--->L3
```

What I want to get in my result query is :  `ROO1,N1,SN2 and ROOT1,N2,SN3`

Im new to cypher and I struggle to get this result, any help would be usefull .

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I assume that the `ID` that you mention is an `id` property.

To get a collection of the node ids in each full path (except for the leaf node):

```
MATCH p=(root {id: 'ROOT1'})-[*]->(leaf)
WHERE NOT (leaf)-->()
RETURN EXTRACT(x IN NODES(p)[..-1] | x.id) AS result;
```

Here is a sample result:

```
+----------------------+
| result               |
+----------------------+
| ["ROOT1","N1","SN2"] |
| ["ROOT1","N2","SN3"] |
+----------------------+
```

Comment: You can simplify the slice to `nodes(p)[..-1]`, a negative index is counted from the end.

Comment: @FrankPavageau: Thanks. I have updated my answer to replace `[0 .. SIZE(NODES(p))-1]` with the much more concise `[..-1]`.